# List Item Wrapping in Game Menu

Tags: list, qt, user-interface, menu, qml

I'm trying to get an infinite scrolling effect with a list of game items by wrapping itself around itself so if you keep pressing down it will wrap around to the first item smoothly.

The effect I'm trying to get is like this image here where there is no breaks in the menu items being listed. [image: Dance Dance Revolution Menu]

I'm currently doing this in Qt Quick QML but I think it can be code agnogstic. I'm also trying not to shift by moving item indices within the list, just moving the Y position of the object.

Here is my code currently (just a normal list positioning)

```
Text
{
    id:root
    //clip: true
    property int spacing
    property int currentIndex
    property int selectedIndex
    property int maxIndex

    property int difference: Math.min(selectedIndex - currentIndex, maxIndex-currentIndex)
    width: 500

    x:  -400 + 30 * Math.abs(difference)
    y: (currentIndex- selectedIndex) * spacing

    Behavior on x { NumberAnimation { duration: 500 } }
    Behavior on y { NumberAnimation { duration: 500 } }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Check out [`PathView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-pathview.html); it should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

So my friend sent me a code snippet on how to do the wrapping I needed. Here's the code for the element item.

```
Text
{
    //externally set
    property int itemIndex
    property int selectedIndex
    property int numberOfElements
    property int span

    //internally set
    property int shortestDistance
    readonly property int distancePerItem: 100

    id: root

    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    anchors.right: parent.right

    anchors.verticalCenterOffset: shortestDistance * distancePerItem
    anchors.rightMargin: Math.abs(shortestDistance) > span ? -contentWidth * Math.abs(shortestDistance) : 0


    Behavior on anchors.rightMargin { NumberAnimation { duration: 500 } }

    Behavior on anchors.verticalCenterOffset { NumberAnimation { duration: 500 } }

    onSelectedIndexChanged: updatePosition()

    function updatePosition()
    {
        shortestDistance = itemIndex - selectedIndex;
        if (shortestDistance > numberOfElements/2)
        {
             shortestDistance -= numberOfElements;
        }
        else if (shortestDistance < -numberOfElements/2)
        {
            shortestDistance += numberOfElements;
        }
    }
 }
```